# Javascript JSON parse unescape quotes?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I have a user entered JSON data which is then saved to other object. But instead of JSON I get `dtExport: '{\\"type\\":\\"polyline\\"}`.

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Please post the problematic code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

var x = '{\"type\":\"polyline\"}';
    x = x.replace(/\"/g, "\"");

and next JSON.parse

results:

```
"{"type":"polyline"}"
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(
I have `var planJson = JSON.parse(message.text)`
And then saving to DB:
`db.merge('plans', planId, { "dtExport": JSON.stringify(planJson) })`
But it's still the same.

Comment: @fivepointseven My answer was edited by Mateusz and it seems to be working fine now.